# classic asp request an input with single quote

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I am trying to read a text area (id= Message) and save it into the database. The problem is that if the user enters a single quote (') in the text, both the codes below fail to handle it.

```
Request("Message")
```

or

```
Replace(Request("Message"),"'","")
```

both fail with the error message

```
Security violation occurred
Incorrect value was passed for field "Message"
```

.

Seems like it fails as soon as it reads `Request("Message")`

Comment: Why not the standard Replace(Request("Message"),"'","''")? Are you not using a parameter?

Comment: I'm not aware of "Incorrect value was passed for field" being an error message in the ASP or Active Scripting environment. Are you using IIS's ASP, or a third-party implementation like Chilisoft ASP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this might be a hosting level security measure to protect against SQL injection. If this is the case the only solution might be to ask your host to disable it (and protect from this yourself) or to add some JavaScript to replace or HTML encode apostrophes when the form is submitted.

Are you testing this on a local computer or just on a site hosted with a web hosting company?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Command-object to securely save userentered data to the database.

```
set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table(message) VALUES(?)"
cmd.CommandType = 1
recordsAffected = 0
call cmd.Execute(recordsAffected, array(Request("Message")&""))

if recordsAffected <> 1 then
  Response.Write "Something went wrong!"
else
  Response.Write "Data saved!"
end if
```

The code above assumes you have an open connection to the database stored in the variable conn.